# How to remove diacritics in pyspark dataframes?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, diacritics

I am wondering how to remove diacritics in Pyspark Dataframe with Python2. I would need something like

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = sc.parallelize([(u'pádlo', 1), (u'dřez', 4)]).toDF(['text', 'num'])

def remove_diacritics(s):
    return unidecode.unidecode(s)

rem_udf = sf.udf(remove_diacritics, StringType())

df.select(rem_udf('text'))
```

unfortunatelly, `unidecode` module is not available in our cluster.

Is there some any natural solution that I am missing excepting manual replacement of all possible characters? Note that the expected result is `[padlo, drez]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use analog of [SQL translate](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.translate) to replace character based on two "dictionaries":

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

charsFrom = 'řá' #fill those strings with all diactricts
charsTo   = 'ra' #and coresponding latins

df = sc.parallelize([(u'pádlo', 1), (u'dřez', 4)]).toDF(['text', 'num'])
df = df.select(sf.translate('text', charsFrom, charsTo),'num')
```

It will replace every occurence of each character from the first string to coresponding character from second string.